# Compare strings, extract unique values from one (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, array, string

In QGIS 3.18.  I am looking for a field calculator expression able to return the values of a string (comma separated) in Field B which are not* also values of a string in Field A.  For example:

- Field A: 2,4,6,8,10
- Field B: 1,2,3,4,5
- Field C (desired result of expression): 1,3,5

I suppose this will be a situation for `string_to_array` and then an array function, but `array_distinct` returns distinct values of one single array; perhaps there is a way to structure the expression such that it will compare the 2 cells, but I've not yet found it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this expression:

```
array_to_string (
    array_remove_all(
        array_foreach (
            string_to_array(field_B),
            if (
                array_contains (string_to_array(field_A),@element),
                '',
                @element
            )
        ), 
        ''
    )
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Great answer by [@Babel](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/88814/babel)!

Another option would be:

`regexp_replace(replace("Field B", string_to_array("Field A"), ''), ',,', ',')`

[image]

The core part of the expression is `replace("Field B", string_to_array("Field A"), '')`, but it will produce `1,,3,,5` so `regexp_replace(~~~, ',,', ',')` was added to remove doubled commas.

Comment: I knew there was a simpler solution to that... great!

Comment: @Babel I believe your solution has much wider application than this!